# How do I generate a sorted edge list for a large, complete, Euclidean weighted graph?

Tags: algorithm, graph

I have a complete Euclidean graph (i.e. edge weights are determined by the Euclidean distance between the nodes, which sit in a 2D space) that is too large (~100k nodes) for the full edge list to sit in memory.

Is there any way for me to generate the edges in order sorted by edge weight?

If I could fit the edge list in memory, I'd just create a list of edge lengths then sort (total time = O(V^2 * E log E)). Otherwise, I'm not sure how to do it other than using a KDTree in some unknown algorithm.

Comment: How would a KD-tree help you? The lower bound is `O(V^2)` and you already know an `O(V^2 log V)` algorithm with low constant factor (external sorting), so I guess any data structure with logarithmic queries will not help you a lot. I guess the best you can hope for is something like `O(V log V + V^2)`, but that looks unlikely to me

Comment: @NiklasB. Not really sure how it would help me actually, I just thought as it was a spatially-motivated data structure (vs. an edge lookup dictionary + a weight function) it might be a part of the solution.

Comment: Also, I know about the closest-pair algorithm given a set of points. The question is how I'd run that multiple times to generate 2nd-closest pair, third-closest pair, etc.

Comment: You can enumerate all pairs, because you will need to store an edge for every pair anyway. Your problem seems to be the sorting, but you don't have to do that in memory

Comment: Sorting outside of memory = disk-based merge sort or MapReduce sort?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting, so yes, disk-based merge sort would be one of the options

Comment: You wouldn't be planning to run Kruskal afterward, would you?

Comment: What kind on operations do you intend? If you are dealing with an euclidean 2D space, you don't have to keep an edge list in memory. You can calculate edge weights when ever you need them, which is a rather simple calculation and might even be faster than searching a value in some edge list.

Comment: What are you trying to do with a sorted list of edges that large? I get the feeling this might be an example of the XY problem. There might be a better way to do what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: Greedy algorithm for 100k point TSP, which requires that I add edges in order from shortest to longest so long as adding an edge doesn't create a vertex of degree > 2.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat: yes, a modified version designed to produce a cycle instead of a MST.

Answer (score 0):

I know Jon Bentley did some work on applying proximity structures to geometric TSP. I'm not sure whether he described an algorithm like this.

Insert all of the points into a kd-tree. Maintain a map from points to degrees (initially 0). Initialize a priority queue where, for each point, there is an entry with value equal to a pair of that point and its nearest neighbor (later, the nearest with whom making the connection would not induce a subtour), and the key is the distance. Maintain a map from points to queue entries in which they are involved (so in C++, for example, it would be more convenient to use a map instead of a priority queue and store a vector of iterators into the map). Initialize a disjoint set data structure for the extant paths, where each root stores the degree-1 endpoints of its path (or the degree-0 endpoint twice).

Repeatedly do the following: pop the priority queue and add the edge, updating the degree map and the disjoint set data structure. Delete vertices newly of degree two from the kd-tree. For each affected entry of the priority queue (had a degree-2 vertex as nearest neighbor, or is one of the endpoints of the new path), remove that entry, look up the three nearest neighbors in the kd-tree (itself, possibly the endpoint of its path, vertex guaranteed not to be on the path already) and write back the appropriate entry.

Actually I'm not sure that eager deletion would be a win. Since the best valid connection for a node is length-nondecreasing over time, you could avoid the deletes out of the priqueue by checking at dequeue time whether the edge is a valid extension. If not, then recompute the priqueue entry.

You may prefer just to use an external sort :)